# Safely pausing and resuming a thread

Tags: java, thread-safety

I want to create a thread to make some HTTP requests every few seconds and is easy to pause and resume at a moments notice.

Is the way below preferred, safe and efficient?

```
public class Facebook extends Thread {

    public boolean running = false;

    public void startThread() {
        running = true;
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            while(running) {
                //HTTP Calls
                Facebook.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hoping that `boolean` read/write will be atomic is a bad idea. Use `AtomicBoolean` or synchronization mechanism

Comment: When paused, it will load all your CPU. At least you should put another "sleep" instruction right after "while (true)", like sleep(200), to let your CPU breath.

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService`; make the `Runnable` you submit check for a variable (boolean, probably) to check whether it should run

Comment: @ortis What problems do you see here with `boolean`?

Comment: OMG the Facebook source got leaked on stackoverflow.

Comment: @ortis A `volatile boolean` will be sufficient for this purposes. It does not particularly matter if it is atomic or not in this situation although it would need to be volatile.

Comment: @fge Or a `Timer`, which doesn't have all the features of the executor service, but is still adequate here. Although the executor services in general are great utilities, and there is no reason *not* to use one either.

Comment: @Jason C you have not guarantee that `boolean` operation will be atomic because its implementation differ across JVM (Windows, Linux, ...). `volatile` does not bring any kind of synchronism, hence, you could read the variable in `while(running)` while writing in `startThread` or `stopThread`.

Comment: @ortis Yes but for 2 second intervals for background HTTP requests, it is highly unlikely that it would matter if that happens and one extra request a few microseconds after a pause (or if it starts one tight loop iteration too late). A volatile boolean will be sufficient *for this purpose*.

Comment: @ortis Also you are confusing levels of atomicity. Writes to a `volatile` boolean (or any volatile variable for that matter) are guaranteed to be atomic by the JLS and guaranteed to be synchronized with reads of that variable by other threads. See 17.4.4. What *you* are referring to is treating the entire "start" and "stop" operation as "atomic", which is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion to using a `Timer` would work better.  If you want to do the threading manually, though, then something more like this would be safer and better:

```
class Facebook implements Runnable {

    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    public boolean running = false;

    public void startThread() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            running = true;
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            running = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    // Wait until somebody calls startThread()
                    while (!running) {
                        monitor.wait();
                    }
                }

                //HTTP Calls
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note in particular:

1. You should generally implement `Runnable` instead of subclassing `Thread`, then use that `Runnable` to specify the work for a generic `Thread`.  The work a thread performs is not the same thing as the thread itself, so this yields a better model.  It's also more flexible if you want to be able to perform the same work by other means (e.g. a `Timer`).
2. You need to use some form of synchronization whenever you want two threads to exchange data (such as the state of the `running` instance variable).  There are classes, `AtomicBoolean` for example, that have such synchronization built in, but sometimes there are advantages to synchronizing manually.
3. In the particular case that you want one thread to stop work until another thread instructs it to continue, you generally want to use `Object.wait()` and a corresponding `Object.notify()` or `Object.notifyAll()`, as demonstrated above.  The waiting thread consumes zero CPU until it is signaled.  Since you need to use manual synchronization with wait/notify anyway, there would be no additional advantage to be gained by using an `AtomicBoolean`.

*Edited to add:*

Since apparently there is some confusion about how to use this (or the original version, I guess), here's an example:

```
class MyClass {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        FaceBook fb = new FaceBook();
        Thread fbThread = new Thread(fb);

        fbThread.start();

        /* ... do stuff ... */

        // Pause the FaceBook thread:
        fb.stopThread();

        /* ... do more stuff ... */

        // Resume the FaceBook thread:
        fb.startThread();

        // etc.

        // When done:
        fbThread.interrupt(); // else the program never exits
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the addition of `wait()`, which prevents the tight loop in the OP's original code. Also a good analysis of the OP's actual posted question.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, real helpful. I've tried this code creating the object Facebook and then calling startThread() with a println statement in the run() method. Nothing seems to run in the loop.

Comment: The `startThread()` method does not make any thread run (not in your version either).  It would be better named "resumeThread" or "enable", or similar.  In a moment I will add some information to my answer on how you use it.

Comment: After learning about intrinsic locks and runnables I can now say thank you for this brilliant model.

Answer (score 3):

**Your Code:**

In your example, the `boolean` should be `volatile boolean` to operate properly. The other issue is if `running == false` your thread just burns CPU in a tight loop, and you probably would want to use object monitors or a [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to actually wait idly for the flag to become `true` again.

**Timer Option:**

I would suggest simply creating a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for this. Each `Timer` implicitly gets its own thread, which is what you are trying to accomplish.

Then create a `TimerTask` (`FacebookTask` below is this) that performs your task and from your main control class, no explicit threads necessary, something like:

```
Timer t;

void resumeRequests () {
    if (t == null) { // otherwise its already running
        t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FacebookTask(), 0, 2000);
    }
}

void pauseRequests () {
    if (t != null) { // otherwise its not running
        t.cancel();
        t = null;
    }
}
```

Note that above, `resumeRequests()` will cause a request to happen immediately upon resume (as specified by the 0 delay parameter); you could theoretically increase the request rate if you paused and resumed repeatedly in less than 2000ms. This doesn't seem like it will be an issue to you; but an alternative implementation is to keep the timer running constantly, and have a `volatile bool` flag in the `FacebookTask` that you can set to enable/disable it (so if it's e.g. `false` it doesn't make the request, but continues checking every 2000ms). Pick whichever makes the most sense for you.

**Other Options:**

You could also use a [scheduled executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) as fge mentions in comments. It has more features than a timer and is equally easy to use; they'll also scale well if you need to add more tasks in the future.

In any case there's no real reason to bother with `Thread`s directly here; there are plenty of great tools in the JDK for this job.

Comment: A `ScheduledExecutorService` (at least the implementations in the JDK) has another advantage: its time source is reliable. This is not the case of a `Timer`. The latter uses `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` which depends on the system time (which can be modified) whereas the former uses `System.nanoTime()` which is guaranteed to "progress forward".

Comment: @fge That's a great point; I have never actually considered that before. Thanks for teaching me something!

Answer (score 0):

I Would recommend you to use [a guarded blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) and attach the thread to a timer

Comment: What does "attach a thread to a timer" mean? `Timer`s already have their own thread.

Comment: By timer i mean any method he can use to calculate the time, not the Timer class specifically